# EF migration on debug vs release build configuration

Tags: entity-framework, migration

This has been asked before in one form or another, but I could not find precise answer.

My release and debug configurations point at different databases and connection factories (Sql vs LocalDB) via config transform.  I need to run migrations separately in dev and prod DBs.  If only connection strings were different then I could use `Update-Database` with corresponding connection strings.  To fully pickup release/debug config I could write a short app to fire migration programmatically, in which case correct connection string/factory combination would be picked up.

The question is: is it possible to achieve same effect without writing an app and only using `Update-Database`?